# addentitytype using dataproperties array not working

Tags: breeze

i am playing with breeze in conjunction with typescript. i am trying to create a type using the following typescript code:

```
   var eto = <breeze.EntityTypeOptions>new Object();
   eto.shortName = "type1";
   eto.namespace = "mod1";
   eto.dataProperties = new Array();
   eto.autoGeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;

   var dpo = <breeze.DataPropertyOptions>new Object();
   dpo.name = "id";
   dpo.dataType = breeze.DataType.Int32;
   dpo.isNullable = false;
   dpo.isPartOfKey = true;

   var dp = new breeze.DataProperty(dpo);
   eto.dataProperties.push(dp);

   dpo = <breeze.DataPropertyOptions>new Object();
   dpo.name = "prop1";
   dpo.dataType = breeze.DataType.Int32;
   dpo.isNullable = false;
   dpo.isPartOfKey = false;

   dp = new breeze.DataProperty(dpo);
   eto.dataProperties.push(dp);            

   var et = new breeze.EntityType(eto);
   store.addEntityType(et);
   store.registerEntityTypeCtor(et.shortName, type1);
```

however the following line is failing:

```
   store.addEntityType(et);
```

it looks like there's a problem when the "dataProperties" is an array, as is the case above, instead of an object... i am a javascript novice so i suspect i am doing something wrong... but it's my suspicion that the breeze code below, specifically line:

```
            propObj.forEach(entityType.addProperty);
```

will never work because the implementation of the addProperty methods makes use of the "this" context... again, i am likely wrong, in which case i would appreciate it if somone could give me a hand. thank you

```
    // Used by both ComplexType and EntityType
    function addProperties(entityType, propObj, ctor) {

        if (!propObj) return;
        if (Array.isArray(propObj)) {
            propObj.forEach(entityType.addProperty);
        } else if (typeof (propObj) === 'object') {
            for (var key in propObj) {
                if (__hasOwnProperty(propObj, key)) {
                    var value = propObj[key];
                    value.name = key;
                    var prop = new ctor(value);
                    entityType.addProperty(prop);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("The 'dataProperties' or 'navigationProperties' values must         be either an array of data/nav properties or an object where each property defines a data/nav property");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**  This has been fixed as of v 1.3.5, available now.

---

Ok, this is a bug, and will be fixed in a release going out later today or tomorrow.... and thanks for finding and reporting it. :)

In the meantime there is a simple workaround.  Just create the EntityType before you add the properties. i.e. ( using raw js instead of TypeScript but you'll get the idea).

```
    var eto = {}
    eto.shortName = "type1";
    eto.namespace = "mod1";
    eto.dataProperties = new Array();
    eto.autoGeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;
    var et = new breeze.EntityType(eto);

    var dpo = {};
    dpo.name = "id";
    dpo.dataType = breeze.DataType.Int32;
    dpo.isNullable = false;
    dpo.isPartOfKey = true;

    var dp = new breeze.DataProperty(dpo);
    et.addProperty(dp);

    dpo = {};
    dpo.name = "prop1";
    dpo.dataType = breeze.DataType.Int32;
    dpo.isNullable = false;
    dpo.isPartOfKey = false;

    dp = new breeze.DataProperty(dpo);
    et.addProperty(dp);

    store.addEntityType(et);
```